# JUnit - some of my class methods don't appear Eclipse JUnit wizard?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

When I run the wizard in Eclipse, not all my methods appear in the list to add to the new test case.

Is this to say I can't test them? Or that if I somehow can, I shouldn't test them?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using JUnit 3 or JUnit 4 tests, or a mix? Also, please accept some of your previous answers.

Comment: A mix but it happens using both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse wizards won't show private methods - you can't call them directly hence you can't test them directly, which might be what you are seeing.

Instead of thinking about which methods you are testing, you might however want to start thinking of testing in terms of testing the behavior of the class.

Comment: Ah I see, didn't think about the type of methods that were omitted. With unit testing, how can I test for things like, if a client is running? If a server is running etc?

Comment: IF you are wanting to see if a server is running, then the test you are writing is not a unit test as understood by most Java programmers. If you are just starting out with automated testing it would probably be worth your while googling "Test driven development" and "behavior driven development". You ought to be able to find some good book recommendations elsewhere on stackoverflow. You'll thank yourself later on if you invest this time now.

Comment: I wasn't testing them but I will need to at some point. I'll take a look at those concepts before I do. Thanks henry!